# Pago payment gateway Integration

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to add a payment module on my Iphone Application that I am going to build,

I want the users to pay using Pago. When webpage loads a button is displayed, on clicking the button a new page opens in a new window.

On that page user enters the payment details and payment is processed. As we have no control over this window, So we are not able to call our custom url to return to our app on payment success.

So how can I return to App on payment success?

Comment: are you asking about paypal>?

Comment: It is 123pago   http://123pago.net.ve/

Comment: I liked your name, and will try to get the answer :)

Comment: any link from where you are implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it. 
Try opening the page in web view and add when the url of the success page match to the url in web view display the success message.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the users to pay using Pago. When webpage loads a button is displayed, on clicking ?  the button a new page opens in a new window.

Does the new page opens inside a webview in your app?

If so, you just have to get the URL you get on payment success (if you can) and use the following web view delegate method to catch the URL:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", request.URL];

  // If not found, load url
  if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"http://you-url"].location == NSNotFound)
  {
    return YES;
  }
  // If found, intercept
  else
  {
    // Do what you want here
    return NO;
  }
}
```

Comment: New page is not opening in webview,same thing opening in safari.

Comment: Ok then i don't know sorry.